# Django testing, change request

Tags: python, django, testing

I have a middleware from secretballot

```
class SecretBallotMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.secretballot_token = self.generate_token(request)

    def generate_token(self, request):
        raise NotImplementedError


class SecretBallotIpMiddleware(SecretBallotMiddleware):
    def generate_token(self, request):
        return request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']


class SecretBallotIpUseragentMiddleware(SecretBallotMiddleware):
    def generate_token(self, request):
        s = ''.join((request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '')))
        return md5(s.encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
```

and I use this in my view (e.g. 'different_view'):

```
token = request.secretballot_token
```

How can I change this token form request in my tests?

```
class BasicTest(TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        self.client.request['secretballot_token']='asd' #??
        response = self.client.post('/different_view/')
```

And I want to send post in this test to /different_view/ but with my own, changed token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to the test the view without running through the middleware, you can use `RequestFactory` to generate a request and pass it directly into your view.

```
def test_one(self):
    # create a request
    request = RequestFactory().post('/different_view')
    request.secretballot_token = 'asd'

    # function based view
    response = different_view(request)
    # class based view
    response = DifferentView.as_view()(request)
```

If you need to test the middleware along with the view, you should pass HTTP headers in your tests instead

```
def test_one(self):
    # pass http headers
    response = self.client.post(path='/different_view'/,
        REMOTE_ADDR='12.34.56.78',
        HTTP_USER_AGENT='...'
    )
```